# ngcsv gives a csv opened in one cell in Excel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel, csv

I used the module ngcsv in order to export some data into a csv file, it is done without any problems, however, when I try to open the downloaded file in Excel the whole line is put in just one cell, normally a correct csv file is open with Excel in different cell and the delimiter (,) is eliminated right ? 
Is that possible using ng-csv ?
Thanks